# Create a complex index on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Is it possible to somehow create an index on an expression so I can, for example, write a query against a field that is string, but meant to be numeric?

For example, I inherited a database that has a column `PolarFactor` which stores values like "234.28234" and is of type `varchar(100)`.

I want to efficiently query that column, getting all rows with values in between 200 and 300.

Would be great if you could do something like this....

```
create index i1 on table(CAST(PolarFactor as Double))
```

This is not valid.

But I am wondering if either there is a way to do it, or if somebody has a better idea.

Comment: Fix the datatype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Use a computed column:

```
alter table t add polarfactor_double as (try_cast(PolarFactor as double)) persisted;

create index i1 on t(PolarFactor_Double);
```

Note that I use `try_cast()` instead of `cast()`, so errors don't cause inserts to break.

Also, you should probably fix your data so `PolarFactor` is stored using the correct data type.  Don't store numbers as strings.